# node.js with mongodb and angularjs data binding

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to receive data from node.js with angularjs.

without angularjs, I can handle mongodb data but with angularjs, I cannot handle it.

when alerting data received from node.js, it shows [object object].

but on jade, no data showing now.

app.get and angularjs works fine but no data binding.

any ideas for me?

thank you for reading!

app.js

```
app.get('/studentlist', (req, res) => {    
    dbs.collection('slist').find({}).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        //res.send(JSON.stringify(result));  
        var data = JSON.stringify(result);
        //console.log(data);
        res.send({ result: data });
        console.log('data sent');
    });   
});
```

angular.js code

```
var app = angular.module("datalist", []);
app.controller('datadisplay', function ($scope, $http) 
    var vm = this;
    vm.mydata = [];
        $http.get('/studentlist').then(function (result) {
            alert(result.data);
            $scope.slist = result.data;
        })

});
```

jade code

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Student list    
    label Search:
        input(ng-model="searchText")
    .studentlist 
        table.table
            thead
                tr
                    th Name
                    th Age
                    th Class                    
            tbody(ng-app="datalist")             
                    tr(ng-controller="datadisplay" ng-repeat"mongo_result in slist | filter:searchText")
                        form(action='/detail', method="POST" class="slist")
                            th
                                {{mongo_result.name}}
                            th
                                {{mongo_result.age}}
                            th
                                {{mongo_result.class}}
                            th
                                button.btn-primary(type="submit") Detail
                            th 
                                button.btn-danger(type="button" class="btnOrderLiterature" data-value="{{mongo_result.age}}" value="{{mongo_result.name}}" ng-click="addLiteratureToSession($event)") Delete
```

Comment: Can you do a console.log of result.data instead of an alert ? To see what it's made of into the console.

Comment: @Sorikairo If I use console.log, it shows nothing and app.get does not show any data with console log. It only shows console.log('data sent')

Comment: Also, do not stringify the result before sending it back in node, just send the json, it's the purpose of node and angular will handle it perfectly :)

Comment: Write console.log(result.data) instead of alert(result.data)into your angularjs handler please, and copy past the object please

Comment: @Sorikairo it does not show any data :(..

Comment: "when alerting data received from node.js, it shows [object object]." But if you do a console.log(result.data) nothing is shown ?

Comment: Do a console.log(result) then.

Comment: @Sorikairo Yeah.. I don't know why.. have tried many ways but not figured out what happened with it.

Comment: Console.log(result) display what ? It will contain something as it's the server response

Comment: @Sorikairo I think it is a problem with Jquery code. I will replace the code into the new js file

Comment: Okay, keep me updated :)

Comment: @Sorikairo it seems that if I use console.log, data handling does not work. I can see   console.log('data sent') but not console.log(result) or others.

Comment: I'm asking you to do the console log into your angularjs code not app.js :(

Comment: @Sorikairo I changed  res.send({ result: result});. is this right? you told me to change like this.

Comment: @Sorikairo yeah, I'm doing what you are meaning but nothing on console..GET /student 200 159ms - 2.21kb
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 304 1ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 3ms
GET /javascripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js 304 2ms
GET /stylesheets/home.css 304 5ms
GET /javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.js 304 5ms
GET /javascripts/bootstrap.js 304 6ms
GET /javascripts/respond.js 304 7ms
GET /javascripts/angular.min.js 304 11ms
GET /javascripts/angular.js 304 11ms
GET /javascripts/details.js 304 9ms
GET /javascripts/studentlist.js 304 1ms
data sent
GET /studentlist 200 52ms - 1015b

Comment: res.send({ result: result}) is okay :)

Comment: The console.log that you are showing me are the nodejs console log into your server, not the one that are displayed into your web browser where the angularjs code runs

Comment: Seems like there is a misunderstanding about how both things works (which is okay)...

The console.log on your nodejs code are displayed into your server terminal
The console.log on your angularjs code are displayed into your browser console, which browser are you using, on what OS ?

Comment: @Sorikairo Oops.. sorry give me a sec ..

Comment: Let's not polute the thread with all our comments, joins me into this stackoverflow chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/141261/nodejs-with-mongodb-thread?tab=general

Comment: @Sorikairo HTML1409: Invalid attribute name character. Attribute names should not contain ("),('),(<), or (=)------------------HTML1503: Unexpected start tag.-------------------HTML1506: Unexpected token.--------------------HTML1509: Unmatched end tag.-------------------------WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.---------------------[object Object]{config: Object {...}, data: Object {...}, status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: Good, so now, can you click into data and show me what's inside ?

Comment: @Sorikairo I must have 20 reputation to talk with you. would you mind if we can use other messenger like skype?

Comment: Yeah sure. Send me your skype id via email : Sorikairox@gmail.com

Comment: you simply add a debugger; after vm.mydata = [];  in the runtime onmousehover to result. there you can see exactly what form of the object you are receiving there.